# chrome.manifest: replace whole window

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am working on an extension to FF. I would like to replace *whole main window* with my own layout. I know how to add and overlay over an existing main window

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://foo/content/foo.xul
```

but how to add a layout that would *substitute* the main window?

This didn't work (I still had the main window):

```
overlay chrome://foo/content/foo.xul
```

Where `foo.xul` starts with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                        
<overlay id="foo-main-overlay"                                               
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/x-javascript"                                  
            src="chrome://foo/content/foo.js" />                             

    <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">                                         

    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`override` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#override):

```
override chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://foo/content/foo.xul
```

This will make sure that `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` is replaced by `chrome://foo/content/foo.xul`. However, I hope that you don't really want to replace the entire browser window...

Comment: Thanks! So if you say that replacing the whole browser window is not the *best* idea... any hint how to configure the overlay so I can replace the content of the main area in FF with my own stuff (example: Collusion plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/collusion/)

Comment: @JakubM.: Load your page into the browser, like the Add-ons Manager?

Comment: Obviously, right. Thanks. By the way, I love your adblockplus!